# Android TextView - Foldername from/on SD card to TextView

Tags: android, arrays, textview, directory

I have an array like this:

```
protected static int[] myTextID = {
    R.id.textView1,
    R.id.textView2,
    R.id.textView3,
    R.id.textView4,
}
```

Now, these are connected to TextViews and currently I'm using static text for them in "strings.xml". For example:

```
<string name="folderNameOne">A placeholder text</string>
```

But I have created folders on the SD card, which I can log the names of like this:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"myFolder");
FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory();
        }
    };
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);

    /* Log the names of each folder in the specified location */
    for (int i=0 ; i< files.length ; i ++) { 
        String theFolderName = String.valueOf(files[i].getName());
        Log.v("LOG Foldernames", theFolderName);
    }
```

**How can I set the text of each TextView to be the corresponding folders name? 
There can be more than 4 folders.**

Thank you.

Comment: better to use listview instead of textview, you can have any number of folders, so my suggestion is to create array of file name and fill listview with that array.

Comment: I'm actually applying this to folder icons in the app. The app should only contain a specified number of folders, let's say 5.